# Prevent dropit.js to close dropdown when i click inside or select checkbox/radio/form/select input

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to add in a dropdown created by dropit plugin - http://dev7studios.com/dropit/# - different options like login/register forms, checkbox, radio buttons, select input etc and i have a problem because the dropdown closes the moment i click anywere in the dropdown, even in empty space - between lines.

I know that i can prevent this close by using event.stopPropagation(); but i have no clue were to add it. So, i have made a demo so you can see /test the issue and hopefully fix it. Thanks

This is how it works with another jquery code `$(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});`
but that is different than dropit code so i don't know how to adjust it...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').dropit();
});



/*
 * Dropit v1.1.0
 * http://dev7studios.com/dropit
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

;
(function($) {

  $.fn.dropit = function(method) {

    var methods = {

      init: function(options) {
        this.dropit.settings = $.extend({}, this.dropit.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          var $el = $(this),
            el = this,
            settings = $.fn.dropit.settings;

          // Hide initial submenus
          $el.addClass('dropit')
            .find('>' + settings.triggerParentEl + ':has(' + settings.submenuEl + ')').addClass('dropit-trigger')
            .find(settings.submenuEl).addClass('dropit-submenu').hide();

          // Open on click
          $el.off(settings.action).on(settings.action, settings.triggerParentEl + ':has(' + settings.submenuEl + ') > ' + settings.triggerEl + '', function() {
            // Close click menu's if clicked again
            if (settings.action == 'click' && $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).hasClass('dropit-open')) {
              settings.beforeHide.call(this);
              $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
              settings.afterHide.call(this);
              return false;
            }

            // Hide open menus
            settings.beforeHide.call(this);
            $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
            settings.afterHide.call(this);

            // Open this menu
            settings.beforeShow.call(this);
            $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).addClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).show();
            settings.afterShow.call(this);

            return false;
          });

          // Close if outside click
          $(document).on('click', function() {
            settings.beforeHide.call(this);
            $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
            settings.afterHide.call(this);
          });

          // If hover
          if (settings.action == 'mouseenter') {
            $el.on('mouseleave', '.dropit-open', function() {
              settings.beforeHide.call(this);
              $(this).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
              settings.afterHide.call(this);
            });
          }

          settings.afterLoad.call(this);
        });
      }

    };

    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method "' + method + '" does not exist in dropit plugin!');
    }

  };

  $.fn.dropit.defaults = {
    action: 'click', // The open action for the trigger
    submenuEl: 'ul', // The submenu element
    triggerEl: 'a', // The trigger element
    triggerParentEl: 'li', // The trigger parent element
    afterLoad: function() {}, // Triggers when plugin has loaded
    beforeShow: function() {}, // Triggers before submenu is shown
    afterShow: function() {}, // Triggers after submenu is shown
    beforeHide: function() {}, // Triggers before submenu is hidden
    afterHide: function() {} // Triggers before submenu is hidden
  };

  $.fn.dropit.settings = {};

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.content{height:300px;background-color:#dedede;}
/*
 * Dropit v1.1.0
 * http://dev7studios.com/dropit
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

/* These styles assume you are using ul and li */

.dropit {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /* dropdown left or right */
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  min-width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu {
  display: block;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  *line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(white), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.menu ul {
  display: none;
}
/* Hide before plugin loads */

.menu ul.dropit-submenu {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  padding: 6px 0;
  margin: 3px 0 0 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.menu ul.dropit-submenu a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #7a868e;
  padding: 0 18px;
}
.menu ul.dropit-submenu a:hover {
  background: #248fc1;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <select name="cars">
              <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
              <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
            <form>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test1">MY STORY</a>
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test2">MY STYLE</a>
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test3">MY STYLE X</a>
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test4">MY STYLE Y</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <form method="post" action="index.html">
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email">
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
              </p>
              <p class="remember_me">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">Remember me on this computer
                </label>
              </p>
              <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login">
              </p>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```